# Vue component list 2 event handling

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Struggling with how to use .sync when you render components from a list. How do I handle the event emitted in my component to update the parent?

Trying to update the `categorySet.gradeCategory.predictionWeight` in the input.

`<category-set v-for="cat in categories" v-bind:key="cat.id" v-bind:category-set="cat"></category-set>`

```
    Vue.component('category-set', {

  props: ['categorySet'],
  template: '            <div class="form-group">\n' +
    '                <label for="gradeRange" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ categorySet.gradeCategory.gradeCategoryName }}</label>\n' +
    '                <div class="col-sm-1">\n' +
    '                    <input id="gradeRange" class="form-control" type="number" v-bind:value.number="categorySet.gradeCategory.predictionWeight" \n' +
    '                           step="0.5" v-on:input="$emit(\'input\', $event.target.value)" > \n' +
    '                </div>\n' +
    '            </div>'
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhmiller/aq9Laaew/10971/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone edited, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do it like the following:

The component is passed the array index and the item (cat), with the item you define the item within the component, then bind the input event which then emits the complete object back to the parent with its index, then the parent sets the item back into the data.

As the `Final Exam` item is nulled the `gradeCategory` property you need to handle/recover from that as your using it in the view. Also the label is the same in the parent, so prefer to use that else it would be null if you used the `gradeCategory` one.

```js
Vue.component('categorySet', {
  template: '#category-set',
  props: ['data', 'index'],
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
         label: this.data.label,
         showInSummary: this.data.showInSummary,
         gradeCategory: Object.assign({
            "gradeCategoryName": null,
            "groupGradeWeight": 0.0,
            "predictionWeight": null,
            "id": this.data.id
         }, this.data.gradeCategory),
         id: this.data.id
       }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    inputOccurred(e) {
      this.$emit('on-change', this.item, this.index)
    }
  }
});

//
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      categories: [
        {
          "label": "Assignments",
          "showInSummary": true,
          "gradeCategory": {
            "gradeCategoryName": "Assignments",
            "groupGradeWeight": 0.0,
            "predictionWeight": null,
            "id": 81
          },
          "id": 81
        }, {
          "label": "Reflections",
          "showInSummary": true,
          "gradeCategory": {
            "gradeCategoryName": "Reflections",
            "groupGradeWeight": 10.0,
            "predictionWeight": null,
            "id": 82
          },
          "id": 82
        }, {
          "label": "Quizzes",
          "showInSummary": true,
          "gradeCategory": {
            "gradeCategoryName": "Quizzes",
            "groupGradeWeight": 10.0,
            "predictionWeight": 10.0,
            "id": 83
          },
          "id": 83
        }, {
          "label": "Attendance \u0026 Participation",
          "showInSummary": true,
          "gradeCategory": {
            "gradeCategoryName": "Attendance \u0026 Participation",
            "groupGradeWeight": 0.0,
            "predictionWeight": null,
            "id": 84
          },
          "id": 84
        }, {
          "label": "Final Exam",
          "showInSummary": true,
          "gradeCategory": null,
          "id": 92
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    syncCategorie(value, index) {
      this.categories[index] = Object.assign(this.categories[index], value);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <category-set v-for="(cat, index) in categories" :key="cat.id" :data="cat" :index="index" @on-change="syncCategorie"></category-set>
  <pre>{{ categories }}</pre>
</div>

<template id="category-set">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gradeRange" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{ item.label }}</label>
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input id="gradeRange" class="form-control" type="number" v-model="item.gradeCategory.predictionWeight" step="0.5" @input="inputOccurred">
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Run the snippet your see it updates the parent fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit the `v-on:input` part when you add a .sync modifier.

`:prop.sync="binding"`

will effectively expands into:

`:prop="binding" @update:prop="value => binding = value"`

( : is just an abbreviation for v-bind: and @ for v-on: )

Comment: I don't think that works. If you look at the fiddle, it doesn't update the parent object. https://jsfiddle.net/rhmiller/aq9Laaew/10971/